# Apache with mod_wsgi segfaults

Tags: python, django, soap, mod-wsgi, zsi

I use apache2 mod_wsgi django to communicate with another soap to get information and return this information use soap!

The apache will return none,and the log with  child pid *** exit signal Segmentation fault (11)!

Who can help me?my English is badly,do you understand what i said?

Comment: Thank you for Graham Dumpleton!I guess that cause this is the ZSI module,because the Segmentation fault (11) occur when I use ZSI to get information from a webservice!How can I fix it?

Comment: I have fix this question,thank you Graham Dumpleton very much!My apache use expat 1.95.7 and python use 2.0.0 so I upgrade expat to 2.0.0 and recompile apache and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes

Comment: I think that is ZSI module use a C extension module!But how can I fix it?I have no idea,only I can fix this is to change apache to nginx.In nginx there is no wrong!